# Error 1054 - Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I don't know why I can't use where clause in this project, it shows up throwing Error Code: 1054.

in this case :Error Code: 1054.  Unknown column '15/05/20' in 'where clause'

```
select * from covid_19_india;
```

```
select `state/unionterritory`,  
        cured, cured, confirmed, 
        round(deaths/confirmed)*100 as mortality_rate
from covid_19_india
where date = `15/05/20`;
```

Here is the file I have imported data from the below file...

[image]

Comment: Consider storing dates using a date data type

Comment: If the data type is DATE better use Standard SQL compliant *date literals*: `DATE `2020-05-15` which requires a YYYY-MMD-D format and avoids ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following, put date between `' '` as single quote is the delimiter for the string and it denotes textual data.

Backticks and regular quotes have different meanings in SQL. *Quotes* (single or double) indicate a literal string, whereas *backticks* are quoted identifiers.

```
select `state/unionterritory`,  
        cured, cured, confirmed, 
        round(deaths/confirmed)*100 as mortality_rate
from covid_19_india
where date = '15/05/20';
```

Comment: `try the following` is not a helpful explanation. Instead of wiring that, you should explain **why** it has to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You use backticks `` ` `` to quote your `15/05/20`, and as of that it becomes an identifier, and is not handled as value. So the database is looking for the column with the name `15/05/20` (like with your `state/unionterritory` column)

You need to change the quoted to `'` (`where date = '15/05/20'`)

Comment: ... or even better change it to single quotes (`'`), the SQL standard way for enclosing literals, hence providing more compatibility with other DBMS...